# Publicate Android App using GitHub repository

Tags: android, google-play

Is any way exists to publicate android app via github, not Google Play ?

I'm goind to do some app for my friends, and want be able update and easy install it without full sized publication.

Comment: github is a platform for open source software share. You can publish the whole project there, not the installable apk like google play

Comment: If your friends want to compile your code themselves, github is sufficient.  Of course if you're just talking about a few friends, you can always just email them the new apks.

Comment: release feature allows to plug any binary files including .apk, and require user allow to install unregistered .apk -- not bad for private app, but it can be better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buddy what i guess is 
github is made for version controlling and publishing your projects codes right overthere for to help people not to publish your apk. If you want to do that u have to spent around 25$ to create a google developer play account and upload your app there.
Concluding : github is not to publish your android apks